# How to improve Apache Wicket for Groovy programming?

Tags: java, groovy, wicket

I'm working right now with Apache Wicket using Groovy language. I was wondering is there any chance to improve Apache Wicket for Groovy programming?

What's on my mind. I want have ability to write code like this:

```
new AjaxLink("ajaxLink", {link, target -> /* some Closure body */ })
```

But without creating decorators like

```
class GroovyWicketAjaxLink extends AjaxLink {
    def clickClosure;

    GroovyWicketAjaxLink(wicketId, onClickClosure) {
        super(wicketId)
        this.clickClosure = onClickClosure
    }

    void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        clickClosure.call([this, target]);
    }
}
```

Maybe there is some way to create some kind of `DefaultWicketGroovyMethods` with support exactly like for `DefaultGroovyMethods`?

Comment: I believe there's some fundamental problems with using Wicket and Groovy together - I'm not sure going with that combination is a good idea if you don't feel like writing a LOT of support code. Wicket is certainly **heavily** invested in a very specific way of doing things. (E.g. the API is heavily geared towards patterns that make use of inheriting framework components etc.)

Comment: Actually, scratch that, apparently Groovy has anonymous inner classes now which was the fundamental problem when I last checked. (The rest still applies, it's very much a Java-style OO framework.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start an open-source project called **Gricket**, a Groovy DSL for Wicket, where you could write stuff like:

```
code = { // i wrote this in a closure, but you can write it in a separate file

    ajaxLink id: "link", onClick: { ->
      // write the link
    }

}
```

Which would be parsed as scripts, and `missingMethod` calls are resolved as instantiation of apache wicket classes:

```
class GricketParser {
  def components = []
  def methodMissing(String method, args) {
    def clazz = "org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html." + method.capitalize() as Class
    def component = clazz.newInstance()
    args[0].each { key, value -> component[key] = value }
  }
}

code.delegate = new GricketParser()
code()
```

You could also apply metaprogramming on top of `String` class instead of parsing a script

---

**Update:**

Seems like [the idea was proposed back](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/200803.mbox/%3C200803071501.41343.no.mail.su@gmail.com%3E) in 2008, with some problems regarding groovy support for anonymous classes. Time for a new `WicketBuilder`? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had created the project that you are asking for. I used ExtensionModule groovy feature, so you just need to import a dsl project from github and start using it.
The syntax for AjaxLink with label will look like this:

```
@Override
void onInitialize() {
 ajaxLink('link') {
     label('label')
     click { AjaxRequestTarget t, AjaxLink link -> // or even without these params

     }
  }
}
```

You can chain components like you are imagine them in your mind :) Feel the groovy freedom with Wicket. All methods inside WicketDSL class includes @DelegatesTo and @ClosureParams annotations, so you can feel great IDE support for DSL. Also @CompileStatic groovy annotation is supported for all your code written with this DSL. It should great increase performance.
Checkout two github branches here:
https://github.com/eugene-kamenev/wicket-groovy-DSL
And feel free to contact me.